# Using len() on TensorFlow ragged tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Normally in TensorFlow you can not use len() on a ragged tensor e.g.

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.ragged.stack([[1],[1,2]])
print(len(x))
```

As ragged tensor does not implement a length method so you get the following expected error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'RaggedTensor' has no len()
```

However, I found that when I create a function to map onto a tf Dataset then for some reason you can call len() on a ragged tensor without error.

```
dataset = dataset.map(lambda path, label: self._process_path(path, label, self.background_data)
...

def _process_path(path, label, background_data):
    ...
    x = tf.ragged.stack([[1],[1,2]])
    print(type(x))
    print(len(x))
    print((x.shape[0]))
    ...
```

Then it will correctly print out the following when used in training:

```
<class 'tensorflow.python.ops.ragged.ragged_tensor.RaggedTensor'>
2
2
```

Is there something obvious I have missed for why this is the case and how this works. Is it something to do with tf dataset mapped functions being converted into graph functions so not run eagerly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ragged tensor usually holds variable size sequence lists. The exact length is quite ambiguous. We need to iterate to get each sequence length.

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.ragged.stack([[1],[1,2]])

len(x.to_list())  # total 2 
for i in x:
    print(len(i))
```

If we pass this to `tf. data. Dataset. from_tensor_slices` - it creates a mini dataset with a separate element for each sequence list of the input:

```
A =  tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)

len(A) # total 2  
for i in A:
    print(len(i))
```